# Object ID or Material ID using Volume Scatter

Tags: volumetrics

If I have volume scatter in the scene both the object ID and material ID passes are affected by the volume scatter:
[image]

with the volume scatter off, ID passes look fine:
[image]

is there a way to get clean ID passes while using volume scatter?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post your entire material nodes.

Comment: This is the volumetric material

https://imgur.com/a/gXenahD

Other than that, the rest is pretty basic.

Comment: I'm not getting any ID mask output with a material that only has a volume and the pass index set to 1. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: you mean this? https://imgur.com/3KQjOyE

Comment: I already had the same setup, but I'm getting no output at all. What version of Blender are you using (bottom right corner of the screen)?

Comment: Did you assign any ID to your mesh? I'm on 2.81a but I believe it was the same on 2.79. Definitely the same on 2.8

Comment: Just to make sure that we're not talking past each other, the objects you're trying the create an ID pass for are the ones depicted in your screenshot and they only have the mix between volume absorption and volume scatter as their material? Or are these objects with an entirely different material, but the volume absorption and scatter is applied to the scene or other objects in the scene. I can reproduce the latter case, but that case makes sense because not every ray that intersects the bounding volume of the volume mesh gets scattered.

Comment: Here's a basic scene which shows the problem (assuming you're running 2.8xx)
https://www16.zippyshare.com/v/W0vxBjZ7/file.html
By the way, thank you for trying to help me on this.

Comment: So, to explain the issue better here's a screengrab of the problem
https://www23.zippyshare.com/v/elm29ww1/file.html